# Find the number of all possible automorphisms for the given graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Find the number of all possible automorphisms for the following graph
>
> [image]

So, this question was in my exam yesterday and I wrote $36$ as an answer. I just want to know if my answer is correct. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Why do you think that is the answer? People will be more willing to help if they can see you have put in some effort. It may also be useful to write down the definition of automorphism, as you understand it, so we know what your level of knowledge is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: OP's graph: 9-cycle of red edges, with blue edges between all vertices 3 red edges apart]

Consider the above coloring of your graph. The blue edges are part of a triangle, and the red edges are not. So any automorphism of the graph must map red edges to red edges and blue edges to blue edges. Any automorphism of the graph must therefore also be an automorphism of the red cycle.

Now there are $18$ automorphisms of the red cycle (identity, rotations and reflections) and each of them is also an automorphism of the given graph. So the total number of automorphisms of the given graph is also $18$.

Comment: Why are there 18 automorphism of the red circle? That's because if you take a point of the circle, say $a$, any automorphism is determined by the image of $a$ ($9$ possibilities) and whether the automorphism preserves the orientation or not ($2$ possibilities).